# iOS Development: Why can't my linker see my class?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios

I just added a class to my Xcode project and the linker is giving me this error...

```
_OBJC_CLASS_$_MyCustomViewController", referenced from:
objc-class-ref-to-MyCustomViewController in MainMenuViewController.o
```

In MainMenuViewController.h, I have `#import "MyCustomViewController.h"`

and I have both `MyCustomViewController.h` and `.m` files in the project.  What are some reasons my linker would have trouble seeing the class?

Thanks so much for you wisdom!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ensure that your .m files are being included in the chosen target. To do this:

Right-click on "Groups & Files" (above your file list on the left) and click "Target Membership". Checkboxes should appear to the left of many of your files, particularly your .m files. Make sure that MyCustomViewController.m has its checkbox checked, and then rebuild.

Comment: Thanks, that did it.  I've never had to do that before, why weren't they checked?  Thanks, again!

Comment: I've occasionally had this problem when switching targets (i.e. between iPhone and iPad targets) or when using a file pulled off of SVN. Not sure what the root cause, but at least I now recognize the error on sight XD .

Comment: Thank god for stackoverflow.  I would have NEVER found that on my own.  Thanks, random dude!